# excel formula to fill rows based on start date and end date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Can you please help with a excel formula to have all the rows populated with dates inbetween the start date and end date already specifed. using the image below i want the dates populated automatically starting in cell A5 and going downwards towards the start date.

I want this automated so when changing the end date the rows update automatically.

[image]

expected output

[image]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support SEQUENCE?

Comment: Also you can do that without formulas, by using `Step value` and `Stop value` in Fill Series menu.

Comment: Do you want to miss out weekends? What about holidays?

Comment: yes i want to miss out weekends. im not concenred about holidays at this point either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only paste this in A5 and pull down an amount of cells as the maximum days you think it will be, eventually.

```
IF(($B$2-(ROW()-5))>=$B$1;($B$2-(ROW()-5));"")
```